# Trying to Export SDF to CSV and save locally using ArcGIS Notebook

Tags: python, csv, arcgis-notebook

```
from IPython.display import display
from arcgis.features import feature
from arcgis.geoprocessing import import_toolbox
import pandas as pd
gis = GIS("https://arcgis.com/","username","password")
item = gis.content.get('layernumber')
flayer = item.layers[0]

#create a spatially enabled dataframe object 
sdf = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_layer(flayer)
sdf. head()

# Filter feature layer records with a sql query. 
sdf = flayer.query(where="Complete LIKE 'yes'").sdf

for a,b,c,d in zip(sdf.columns[::4], sdf.columns[1::4],sdf.columns[2::4], sdf.columns[3::4]):
    print("{:<30}{:<30}{:<30}{:<}".format(a,b,c,d))
    
# Return a subset of columns 
sdf[['Label', 'Complete', 'Completed_By', 'Ribbon_', 'use_','Light_Less_5m', 'Heavy_Less_5m', 'Light_and_Heavy_Greater_5m', 'Paid_By', 'Additional']]

#Export as CSV 
"sdf.to_csv (r'C:\Users\steven.kenny\Documents\CLM_Files.csv', 'w', index = False, header=True)
```

I can successfully return a subset of columns. The problem arises when I try to export as a csv and save on my pc. I am using arcgis notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this can be done in one step. The notebook resides on the ArcGIS Enterprise server, so the API is not going to be aware of your local file system.

If you don't need to do this in one step, you can save it to a location that's local relative to your code, and then download it using the Files menu on the page where you are writing your notebook.

[image: image of ArcGIS notebook menu]